# Executing JS code retrieved with Ajax using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $.post to load some js code from a MYSQL database. How do I execute it?

Comment: You've stored a jquery code in your MySQL database?

Comment: you put your js code into you mysql database? why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146069/is-it-possible-to-store-javascript-in-a-database

Comment: Here's a guess as to why you would store javascript code in a database: that makes it 1) accessible from multiple applications, and 2) easy to maintain.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, @Luke: True, storing the code in the database might not be necessary, but we don't know the context. I'm pretty sure http://jsfiddle.net/ uses a database as well ;)

Comment: And if the request was hijacked and other code injected in its place? Proper checks would need to be performed to make sure the code being executed is the code expected.

Comment: I agree with these guys there are proper use cases but you need to be really careful.

Comment: @Eli: That could happen with any request and is not specific to this scenario. Do you check whether code was injected in the SO site your are viewing?

Comment: I understand that, but if you are returning and `eval`ing a string, you would need to inspect the string first before executing. I can't say this is an efficient or recommended process.

Comment: @Luke: It's a quiz thing for schools. The code is in a db so that a teacher can open windows, send alerts to all the students.

Comment: PHP is generating the code, a user can't input it themself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.eval = function(str) {
    eval(str);
}

$.fn.eval = function(str) {
    eval(this.selector);
}

$.post(url, function(data) {
    $.eval(data);
    //$(data).eval();
});
```

Jokes aside. You can use `eval` to run a snippet of JavaScript. I'm sure everyone else will tell you why `eval` is evil.

Ideally though what your doing is bad. There's a far better way to solve your problem that doesn't involve grabbing code from a database.

Comment: Big remark. The words eval and evil only differ one letter. For a reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (instead of `$.post`) with the the `dataType` option set to `script`:

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching unless option "cache" is used. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

Comment: You forgot to mention he probably doesnt want to load snippets of code from his database.

Comment: @Raynos: I think this was mentioned often enough.